# Statistical method to control for differences

Tags: statistical-significance

here's a problem I am trying to solve with no luck so far.

Say I am working off two different horse racing tracks - Track A and Track B for a racing distance of 1200m. I have race time information on a historical basis for both the tracks. I can easily compute the pars/averages for each track : Mean(RaceTime). I can also easily compute the pars/averages adjusted for the class rating (a discrete variable where 1 = higher quality races and 5 = lower quality races) by doing group_by(RaceClass) %>% mutate(RaceTime_cls_adjusted = mean(RaceTime)). That's the easy bit.

What I am trying to achieve thou is derive a rating or a score that might be comparable across Track A & Track B AND across different race class. The subtle difference here is that Track A always has higher quality races so the pars are lower compared to Track B. This subtle difference could be tracked by the class rating system (i.e Track A might have races from class 1 to 5 where Track B might just have races from class 3 to 5).

What's the best statistical way of controlling these effects?

Regards

Comment: I can not understand what are you trying to achieve... Are you trying to predict the rating of the race if you know the Track?

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply. The end goal is to have a single rating number that is comparable after Track A and Track B (remembering that Track A has higher quality races, a discrete variable in dataset represented by class, as compared to Track B).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that such a rating number should be indicative of the race times, i.e. if track A has a lower rating number than track B, then the average race times on track A are lower than those of track B (let's assume only class 1 races happen on both track A and B)?

Comment: Correct. For sake of clarity - lets assume that Class 1 is the only class of horses that run at Track A and Track B. Further assume that for a 1200m dist, the par score for Track A is 70 sec and par score for Track B is 70.20 sec (difference purely due to topography) then I would end up assigning a score of rating 100. In effect the rating number becomes indicative of the race time.A 100 rated horse would run par race times either at Track A or Track B.

Comment: So the score should be indicative of the race times, however it should not depend on average race time differences due to topography?

Comment: Yes but the main reason the average race times are different between Track A and Track B is because Track A has higher quality races (as governed by class factor variable -  1 = higher quality races and 5 = lower quality races) . So in essence, I am looking for a way to derive a speed rating that would account for the differences in race class across Track A & Track B.

Comment: I believe there is no one "best" way to derive such a score, it depends highly on the distribution of race times across race classes (not even taking account the topology). If e.g. it was so that you would expect a class 1 race to be twice as fast as a race 2 class and a class 2 race to be twice as fast as a class 3 race and so on, then for a given track you could use the average race times of the available race classes, divide them by 2^{race class} and average again. I am afraid without more insight into the data, no generally applicable "good" solution can be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder about using a random effects model to model the time of each horse in each race. A key prequisite is that you would see most horses multiple times and ideally a good number of both tracks.

You would assume that each horse has a certain "quality" that varies across horses, but unless you know more about a horse a single stand-out performance is scaled back a little to average. This rating/quality could either be fixed across all time or allowed to vary across time (seems more realistic), but would probably be (almost) fixed for some reasonable time period like a few months or a year (a very simplistic way of achieving that would be to assign a horse a different ID for each year of its age or something like that). Each race probably also has a random effect (things you do not know about that race on that day like the weather might have some effect). Additionally, the track has an effect (if you had enough tracks you could make that random, but with two tracks that dose not make sense).

The next question would be how to account for how competitive the race is - maybe the race class variable you have for that would be suitable. Perhaps that's too simplistic, e.g. a really good horse may not have to try so hard in a less competitive race.

Another question is what kind of distribution is suitable for modeling race times for each horse. I have no domain knowledge, so this is just a wild guess, but modeling log(time) and assuming normally distributed residuals might be a good first try.

Using the notation used in the `lme4` R package (one possible package one could use, there's of course also e.g. `rstanarm` and many other modeling tools that may be suitable), a reasonable model might thus look like this:
`glmer(logtime ~ (1|horse+race) + track + raceclass)`.

You would then want to extract the estimated random effects for each horse and those would give you a rating.

Note that there could be quite a few things wrong with this model. For a start, we assume that if a horse is better on one track than another horse, it is also better on the other track (that does not mean it always needs to win on both tracks, there is of course randomness, but if you could hypothetically re-do races lots of times, the same horse would win more often on both tracks). That may not be true, if one horse can somehow cope better with the conditions on one track (e.g. longer vs. shorter, more sloped, requiring more burst speed vs. endurance, or whatever else may be different across these tracks). If there are issues like that, then a single number may simply be incapable of capturing them. Then, you may need a more complex model that ideally models these differences between tracks (and ideally across even more tracks).

Comment: Thanks Bjorn - your understanding of the problem is spot on accurate. Let me give it a bit more thought, I will try and implement your suggestion to see if it works for me. Your detailed answer is greatly appreciated. Cheers